# Provide link to fetch Google Calendar(Online) events in Android application

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch events from Google Calendar(Online) using Google Calendar API's in Android application but can't find what library need to import in my Android project. Provide link to import exact library to import in my Android application project.

Comment: refer the official google doc https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp

Comment: I went from your specified link but got confused which .jar need to import to get com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar class.

Comment: u dont need to add any .jar files.. use the rest calls

Comment: I am new in Android and don't know how can i use rest calls, can u provide some sample code to manage it?

Comment: To use rest calls is it necessary to build Android project in Android Studio/Gradle because currently i am using Android with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Google Calendar API** directly importing to your project. By using that you can **create, view, edit and delete** any activity.

For more info see this following page.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Answer (score 1):

u can either use rest,client libraries to access google calendar api's ... client api will be size overhead .. so better use rest calls ... here is the link which explains rest calls and json parsing ...http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: To use rest calls is it necessary to build Android project in Android Studio/Gradle because currently i am using Android with Eclipse.

Comment: Can you please provide at least single rest call to authenticate user for Google Calendar API because don't know rest call url and how to pass parameter to them.